# Xcode 8.1 Choose an initial device view showing only iPhone 7 and 7s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

In `Xcode 8.1`, I am unable to choose `iPhone 6/6s Plus`. Only `iPhone 7/7s` are present. Please help why 6/6s is not given in the drop down list.

[image]

Comment: IPhone 6 and 7 has same screen size

Answer (score 2):

iPhone 7/7s have the same display size as iPone 6/6S. So either of them will work the same. The aim is to provide all possible screen size and as few are redundant so they are not included in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it less as choosing an "initial device view" and more of an "initial screen size view". In this respect the iPhone 6, 6s and 7 have the same screen size, as do the 6+, 6s+ and 7+. With this in mind it would be pointless to show the 6s/6s+ in the drop down as selecting it would ultimately be the same as selecting the 7/7+.

So not a bug, intended (and logical) functionality.

Answer (score 1):

That is just for the frame of your storyboard, as the frame for iPhone 6, iPhone 6s and iPhone 7 are all similar, in the same way frame for iPhone 6 +, iPhone 6s + and iPhone 7 + are similar so initially they are giving you option to chose initial layout.

After selecting an initial device, all the views in your storyboard will converted to that frame.

Now when you run your app then you are able to see all the simulators from there.

Comment: But, if I choose iPhone 7, all the layouts are messed up. Initially, the storyboard is developed using xcode 7.3.1

Comment: You just need to select your View Controller and select Update Frames, if all the layout are set properly previously, then it will work

Comment: Yeah. I agree. But the viewcontrollers have "delete conflict constraints" when iPhone 7 is selected. Whereas it was perfect in iphone 6s and lower versions

Comment: Thats what i am saying, if previously your layouts are managed for all the devices then after Updating Frames, you will not face any problem, If you are getting the issues then may be there are some issues with your constraints

Comment: Okay. I will check anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select iphone 6s as a initial device you can choose device from bottom on your storyboard.please find image -

If you want devices list in your simulator you can add more devices from **add new device**

[image]